# Closest pair approach

Tags: java

This is how i tried to implement closest pair algo in my java code but seems there is error in return the value

here is my code, kindly correct the code inorder to get right answer.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Main
{
    public static int closest(int[][] array, int n){
        int dmin = (int)Math.sqrt((int)Math.pow((array[0][0]-array[1][0]),2)+(int)Math.pow((array[0][1]-array[1][1]),2));
        int index1=0,index2=0;
        for(int i = 0 ; n-1 > i ; i++ ){
            for(int  j = 0 ; i+1 > j ; j++ ){
                int d = (int)Math.sqrt((int)Math.pow((array[i][0]-array[j][0]),2)+(int)Math.pow((array[i][1]-array[j][1]),2));
                if(d < dmin){
                    dmin = d;
                    index1 = i;
                    index2 = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return index1;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = obj.nextInt();
        int[][] array = new int[n][n];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < n; j++){
                int c = obj.nextInt();
                array[i][j] = c;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(closest(array,n));
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be 2 results? The indexes of the 2 closest points?

Comment: Also, I don't think you are checking all the pairs: `for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) { for (int j = i+1 ; j < n ; j++ ) { ... } }`

Comment: And the array in `main` should be `int[][] array = new int[n][2];`

Comment: Your question didn't clearly specify what you want to obtain. If you also want to use `index2`, you should initialize it correctly to `1`.

Comment: Casting to `int` inside `Math.sqrt` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops include combinations `j=i`, which trivially give `d=0`.

Comment: In fact, your hint made me realize that my initial answer was wrong. The question just uses `(i, j)` differently than I would have.